# Why encrypt hls files instead of just securing access to them?

Tags: encryption, video, http-live-streaming, drm

I am implementing an application that supports video on demand. I ended up converting my videos to hls files for performance.
Now, for security, I restricted access to all .m3u8 and .ts files via a token authentication (jwt). Then I saw I could also encrypt hls files using AES and then control who can access the decryption key.
But I don't understand the point of encrypting files then securing access to the key. Is it better security than just securing access to the files like I did ? (Knowing that files are delivered through https)

One last question about DRM.

Edit: Question below answered by this topic I found later : [what-is-the-value-added-by-drm-compared-to-encrypted-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017530/what-is-the-value-added-by-drm-compared-to-encrypted-streams?rq=1)

In the current state, only authorized users have access to the videos. On the other hand, it is very easy for them to download them with a plugin. In terms of security, what I understood was that DRM would allow me to make it difficult for authorized users to download my videos. Did I understand the security utility correctly ?

I implemented a JWT based authorization access to hls files which feels fine for my security needs for now which is : securing access to videos to authorized users.

Comment: Interesting question and answer. Basically, from what I understand, files encryption is usefull if files are uploaded on a public storage like a CDN ? Which means If files are stored on a private storage, a basic route authentication is enough and file encryption wont make a difference ?